# Navigation p:commandButton Primefaces Mobile

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

In my app if the login is successful in `<pm:view id="mobileLogin">` the next view is `<pm:view id="mobileTree">`. In the mobileTree view I would like a commandButton to call a logout method that would return the String '`pm:mobileTree?reverse=true'`. The problem is that this is not working. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
 <!-- Login View -->
    <pm:view id="mobileLogin">
        <pm:header title="LiteDoc" />

        <pm:content>
            <h:form id="mobileLoginForm">
                <p:outputPanel id="container">
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not loginManager.loggedIn}" >
                        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginManager.username}" />
                        <p:watermark for="username" value="Login" />
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{loginManager.password}" />
                        <p:watermark for="password" value="Senha" />

                        <p:separator />

                        <p:commandButton value="Login" icon="refresh" process="@form" update=":mobileTreeForm" action="#{loginManager.loginMobile}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </pm:content>
    </pm:view>

    <!-- Tree View -->
    <pm:view id="mobileTree">
        <pm:header title="LiteDoc">
            <!-- Here's the problem --><p:commandButton value="Go" action="pm:mobileLogin?reverse=true" />
        </pm:header>

        <pm:content>
            <h:form id="mobileTreeForm">

                <p:dataList  value="#{cabinetManager.cabinets}" var="cabinet" rendered="#{loginManager.loggedIn}">
                    <p:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{cabinet.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataList>

            </h:form>
        </pm:content>
    </pm:view>
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided? Don't forget to accept the answer that helped (most)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to execute a method in the server and navigate to other `pm:view` is this

```
 <p:commandButton value="Text of the button" actionListener="#{youBean.yourLogOutMehod}" action="pm:theViewYouWantToNavigate" update="theViewYouWantToNavigate" />
```

Other way that you can navigate in mobile views es is using a header

```
<pm:view id="youSourceView">
        <pm:header title="YourTitleView">
            <f:facet name="left"><p:button value="HOME" icon="home" href="#yourHomeViewID?reverse=true"/></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="left"><p:button value="BACKVIEW" icon="back" href="#yourBackViewID?reverse=true"/></f:facet>
        </pm:header>
        <pm:content>
           <!-- your content in the view -->
        </pm:content>      
</pm:view>
```

You could try to log out in you Bean and do a simple redirect to the /loginPage.jsf it will refresh the url and load by default the first `pm:view`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in PrimeFaces' mobile manual (page 12), if you want to call a server action and, after that, navigate to a `pm:view` with id `myViewId`, you have to do the following:

```
<p:commandButton value="Logout" oncomplete="PrimeFaces.navigate('#myViewId', {reverse : 'true'})" action="#{loginBean.logout}" />
```